# Jquery in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a Jquery function but I need to apply it on a website that is working with AngularJs

What are the steps I should follow to make this function work in Jquery website. What should I do or what is the correct way to use it?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.container') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('.container') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
  });
});
```

Comment: Use CSS? `height: 100%;`

Comment: I can not use height: 100%, this is a somewhat complicated case and I need to apply this example to my website: http://jsfiddle.net/eamCj/

Comment: `height: 100%;` still works.  http://jsfiddle.net/eamCj/1/

Comment: yes, but need to work with AngularJS

Comment: @yorchp You don't need Angular if solution is a simple static CSS style declaration.

Comment: @Stewie No, I need that height to be variable, I have 12 years of being front end, I understand that I can do with css and jquery, but this case is different from the conditions I need the div has a variable height declared from html

The question is not whether or not I can do in css, is more like inserting a Jquery to work on Angular JS

Comment: @yorchp Consider explaining **why** your CSS needs to be set from Angular. Also contemplate showing what you've tried, because your question (and your comments) put you directly into "[Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)" category. I'm sure you don't  want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and Angular at the same time with no special accommodations. However, you probably shouldn't. You can do almost everything you want to do with jQuery directly in Angular and if you just use Angular you'll have all of the details about your views in a single place.

I suspect that what you're trying to do here is to use jQuery to manipulate some DOM element that is generated by Angular. The problem you're having is that the Angular hasn't rendered the DOM element by the time your jQuery code runs at document ready. If you really want to do this, you have two options:

1) run the jQuery on a DOM element that exists outside of your angular view.

2) Add your jquery to an event in Angular or something else that triggers after angular is done rendering.